# BeautifulSoup python - save value of tag as string

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm new at BeautifulSoup and have scoured the online docos but couldn't find what I was after, I just need to store the value of a tag into a variable so that it can be written to a file afterwards

Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
f = open('C:\test.txt', 'w')
url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2011/1/1/DailyHistory.html?MR=1"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
table = soup.find('table', id="historyTable").tbody
rows = table.findAll('tr') #get all rows
cols = rows[1].findAll('td') #get 2nd row
meanTemp = cols[1] # get 2nd column
alt = meanTemp('span')[1]
print alt
dayTemp = alt.contents
print dayTemp
f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
```

It prints this:

```
<span class="b">8</span>
[u'8']
```

and then gives this error:

```
    f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp + '\n')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

i.e.: I would like the `print dayTemp` line to actually print `8` instead of `[u'8']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your error it seems the solution is:

```
f.write(timestamp + ',' + dayTemp[0] + '\n')
```

Comment: for debugging, try raising an exception right after the `f.write()`. For example: `raise 1`. Just to see it writes the correct thing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `[u'8']` is a `list` containing one object, a Unicode string. If you want to get the (only) object in that list, you index it to get its first entry:

```
[u'8'][0] # is u'8'
```

or you can pattern-match its value out:

```
[a] = [u'8'] # now a is u'8'
```

Comment: [u'8'][0] prints 8 but dayTemp[0] does not

Comment: Then `dayTemp != [u'8']`. Try `print type(dayTemp)` and see whether you get a list.

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous answers if you're not sure about the contents of your span tag you can use:

```
f.write(timestamp + ',' + '<sep>'.join(dayTemp) + '\n')
```

Where <sep> is a separator of your choice.

Comment: what is the purpose of the extra separator? Is it to handle cases where the data being extracted has embedded commas?

Comment: No. Since dayTemp is a list (you assigned alt.contents which is a list of child nodes, and as you can see it prints [u'8'] which is one element list), you join it using a separator. The separator can be empty if you like. The bonus is that it takes care of cases when dayTemp is empty (i.e. alt has no child nodes, even text ones) or when it has more than one element.